# SQL Query to Update One Column Based on Data from Another

Tags: sql, lookup, lookup-tables

I need to update a table column in one table with data from another based on whether a specific id matches.

Basically, I have the following schema:

TABLE accounts
FIELD old_user_id

TABLE users
FIELD old_user_id
FIELD new_user_id

I need to loop through all old_user_id's in the accounts table checking them against the old_user_id field in the users table, and then take the new_user_id value in the users table and replace the old_user_id value in the accounts table.

Seems like a simple thing to do but as my SQL is not amazing I'm struggling with working this out.

Comment: Would this query work UPDATE `sugar_accounts` LEFT JOIN `sugar_users` ON `sugar_users.old_user_id` = `sugar_accounts.old_user_id` SET `sugar_accouts.old_user_id` = `sugar_users.new_user_id`;

Answer (score 1):

Try This:

```
          UPDATE A 
          SET
                 A.old_user_id = U.new_user_id
          FROM Accounts A
          JOIN   Users U
          ON A.old_user_id = U.old_user_id
```